# What is the meaning of「もう」in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> もう一軒{いっけん}と参{まい}りましょう

I understand 「もう」to mainly mean "already" or "soon" but its usage in this sentence confuses me. Could anyone explain to me why it's natural here?

Comment: If you check a dictionary you'll find that there are other common meanings for もう: https://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%82%E3%81%86 If this doesn't help then please modify your question to explain why. Please also ensure that your Japanese sentences look like you expect -- see edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mou means "more" in this sentence.
so you can say " Lets visit more house
(a house)"